# Setting the default text color of MUI Typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a good understanding of how to style MUI `<Typography>` thanks to the various examples available. I also understand how to define and use the global MUI theme.

But is it possible for a MUI `<Typography>` to adopt `color='text.primary'` by *default*...? If I don't add this attribute, the color is always black, instead of the custom color I've set for `text.primary`.

Or is the preferred approach to always override / never use `<Typography>` directly, by defining an application-specific component for e.g. the standard body text, to ensure it has the correct color?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can make your own component passing preferred color as default if it is not provided, it is a known react pattern named [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

```
const MyTypography = ({color='text.primary', ...rest}) => (
  <Typography {...rest} color={color} />
)
```

You can also configure the material [theme](https://mui.com/customization/theming/) be always your preferred color, here is [the default theme](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/)

```
import type { Components,Theme } from "@mui/material";

export const MuiTypography = (theme: Theme): Components["MuiTypography"] => ({
  defaultProps: {
    color: "text.primary",
  },
});

const initialTheme = createMuiTheme({
    typography, // for font size and variants mapping
    // ... other theme config
});

const theme = createMuiTheme(initialTheme, {
    components: {
      MuiTypography: MuiTypography(initialTheme)
    }
})
```